# Filling in for missing values by name. pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that I need to fill in the blanks of the ID.

```
ID      Name    
        Adam
101     Adam 
        Adam
101     Adam 
102     Ben 
102     Ben 
        Cathy 
        Cathy
103     Cathy
```

What I need:

```
ID     Name 
101    Adam 
101    Adam 
101    Adam 
101    Adam 
102    Ben 
102    Ben 
103    Cathy
103    Cathy
103    Cathy
```

I tried using `df['Name'].ffill()` but does not work when trying on multiple names.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `first`

```
df['ID'] = df.groupby('Name')['ID'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['ID'] = df.groupby('Name')['ID'].transform('first')
print(df)
```

---

```
      ID   Name
0  101.0   Adam
1  101.0   Adam
2  101.0   Adam
3  101.0   Adam
4  102.0    Ben
5  102.0    Ben
6  103.0  Cathy
7  103.0  Cathy
8  103.0  Cathy
```

Answer (score 2):

If the empty values are `NaN`s you can `.groupby` by `Name` and then tranfsorm the `ID` column:

```py
df['ID'] = df.groupby('Name')['ID'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ID   Name
0  101   Adam
1  101   Adam
2  101   Adam
3  101   Adam
4  102    Ben
5  102    Ben
6  103  Cathy
7  103  Cathy
8  103  Cathy
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# You can use 'max' or 'first'
df['Name'] = df.groupby('Name')['ID'].transform('max').astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
    ID   Name
0  101   Adam
1  101   Adam
2  101   Adam
3  101   Adam
4  102    Ben
5  102    Ben
6  103  Cathy
7  103  Cathy
8  103  Cathy
```

If your blank values are empty strings, you have to replace `''` by `NaN` before:

```
df['ID'] = (df.replace({'ID': {'': np.nan}})
              .groupby('Name')['ID'].transform('max')
              .astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
    ID   Name
0  101   Adam
1  101   Adam
2  101   Adam
3  101   Adam
4  102    Ben
5  102    Ben
6  103  Cathy
7  103  Cathy
8  103  Cathy
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
df.sort_values(['Name', 'ID']).ffill()
```

---

Alternatively:

```
(df.drop_duplicates().dropna()
 .merge(df, on='Name', how='right', suffixes=('', '_y'))
 .drop('ID_y', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    ID   Name
0  101   Adam
1  101   Adam
2  101   Adam
3  101   Adam
4  102    Ben
5  102    Ben
6  103  Cathy
7  103  Cathy
8  103  Cathy
```